# Exchange 2013 Management Shell fails to connect to local server

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, winrm

After installing Exchange 2013 on Server 2012, apparently successfully  I find that Exchange Management Shell run on the Exchange Server fails with the message:

> VERBOSE: Connecting to SERVER2012.WARATAH.LOCAL.
>   New-PSSession : [server2012.waratah.local] Connecting to remote server server2012.waratah.local failed with the
>   following error message : WinRM cannot complete the operation. Verify that the specified computer name is valid, that
>   the computer is accessible over the network, and that a firewall exception for the WinRM service is enabled and allows
>   access from this computer. By default, the WinRM firewall exception for public profiles limits access to remote
>   computers within the same local subnet. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
>   At line:1 char:1
>   + New-PSSession -ConnectionURI "$connectionUri" -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Excha ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.Manageme....RemoteRunspace:RemoteRunspace) [New-PSSession], PSRemotin
>      gTransportException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WinRMOperationTimeout,PSSessionOpenFailed

WinRM seems OK when I test with command line WinRM QuickConfig

> C:\Users\Administrator\Downloads>winrm quickconfig
>   WinRM service is already running on this machine.
>   WinRM is already set up for remote management on this computer.

I can ping Server2012.waratah.local OK

I've tried removing Microsoft Security Essentials anti-virus to no avail.

Any other ideas welcome